# How to find the concentration of barium ions in a mixture of barium sulfate and barium thiosulfate?

Tags: aqueous-solution, solubility, solutions, precipitation

I have a hard time with selective precipitation problem.

> A mixture of $\ce{BaSO4}$ and $\ce{BaS2O3}$ is shaken with pure water until a saturated solution is formed. Both solids remain in excess. What is $[\ce{Ba^{2+}}]$ in the saturated solution? $K_\mathrm{sp}(\ce{BaSO4}) = 9 \times 10^{-11}$ and $K_\mathrm{sp}(\ce{BaS2O3}) = 4 \times 10^{-10}$.

My solution:

Because $K_\mathrm{sp}$ of $\ce{BaSO4} < \ce{BaS2O3}$, $\ce{BaS2O3}$ will dissolved first. When $\ce{BaS_2O_3}$ dissolved, the concentration of $[\ce{Ba^{2+}}] = [\ce{S2O3^2-}] = \sqrt{K_\mathrm{sp}(\ce{BaS2O3})} = 2 \times 10^{-5}$.

That means, in the solution, there are:

\begin{align}
[\ce{Ba^2+}] &= 2 \times 10^{-5}\\
[\ce{S2O3^2-}] &= 2 \times 10^{-5}\\
[\ce{SO4^2-}] &= \frac{K_\mathrm{sp}(\ce{BaSO4})}{[\ce{Ba^2+}]} = \frac{9 \times 10^{-11}}{2 \times 10^{-5}} = 4.5 \times 10^{-6}
\end{align}

But the solution is $\ce{[Ba^2+]} = \sqrt{4.9 \times 10^{-10}}$.

What have I missed?

EDIT 1 : 
\begin{align}
\ce{BaSO4 &<=> Ba^2+ + SO4^2- }\\
\ce{BaS2O3 &<=> Ba^2+ + S2O3^2- }
\end{align}

The Solubility Product Equation :

\begin{align}
K_\mathrm{sp}(\ce{BaSO4}) &= [\ce{Ba^2+}] \times [\ce{SO4^2-}] \\
K_\mathrm{sp}(\ce{BaS2O3}) &= [\ce{Ba^2+}] \times [\ce{S2O3^2-}]
\end{align}

When the solids dissolves, it will produce $\ce{Ba^2+}$ ion, $\ce{SO4^2-}$ ion and $\ce{S2O3^2-}$ ion.

$\ce{BaSO4}$ will stop dissolving when $\ce{Ba^2+}$ ion concentration in solution when multiply with $\ce{SO4^2-}$ ion concentration is equal to solubility product of $\ce{BaSO4}$, which is $K_\mathrm{sp}(\ce{BaSO4}) = 9 \times 10^{-11}$

And at the same time,

$\ce{BaS2O3}$ will stop dissolving when $\ce{Ba^2+}$ ion concentration in solution when multiply with $\ce{S2O3^2-}$ ion concentration is equal to solubility product of $\ce{BaS2O3}$, which is $K_\mathrm{sp}(\ce{BaS2O3}) = 4 \times 10^{-10}$

Solubility of $\ce{BaSO4}$ in water is 
\begin{align}
 s &= \sqrt{K_\mathrm{sp}(\ce{BaSO4})}\\
 s &= \sqrt{9 \times 10^{-11}} \\
 s &= 3 \times 10^{-5.5}
\end{align}

Solubility of $\ce{BaS2O3}$ in water is 
\begin{align}
 s &= \sqrt{K_\mathrm{sp}(\ce{BaS2O3})}\\
 s &= \sqrt{4 \times 10^{-10}}\\
 s &= 2 \times 10^{-5}
\end{align}

Now, when the solids is mixed in water, There should be $[\ce{SO4^2-}] =3 \times 10^{-5.5} $ and $[\ce{S2O3^2-}] =2 \times 10^{-5} $.

Now I confuse what ion concentration should I use to determine $[\ce{Ba^2+}]$

EDIT 2:

\begin{align}
K_\mathrm{sp}(\ce{BaSO4}) &= [\ce{Ba^2+}] \times [\ce{SO4^2-}] \\
\frac{K_\mathrm{sp}(\ce{BaSO4})}{[\ce{Ba^2+}]} &= [\ce{SO4^2-}] \\
\end{align}
and 
\begin{align}
K_\mathrm{sp}(\ce{BaS2O3}) &= [\ce{Ba^2+}] \times [\ce{S2O3^2-}] \\
\frac{K_\mathrm{sp}(\ce{BaS2O3})}{[\ce{Ba^2+}]} &= [\ce{S2O3^2-}] \\
\end{align}

From [@santimirandarp answer](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/115750/79443), I got that :

\begin{align}
[\ce{Ba^2+}] &= [\ce{S2O3^2-}] + [\ce{SO4^2-}]\\
[\ce{Ba^2+}] &= \frac{K_\mathrm{sp}(\ce{BaS2O3})}{[\ce{Ba^2+}]} + \frac{K_\mathrm{sp}(\ce{BaSO4})}{[\ce{Ba^2+}]}\\
[\ce{Ba^2+}] &= \frac{4 \times 10^{-10}}{[\ce{Ba^2+}]} + \frac{9 \times 10^{-11}}{[\ce{Ba^2+}]}\\
[\ce{Ba^2+}] &= \frac{4.9 \times 10^{-10}}{[\ce{Ba^2+}]} \\
[\ce{Ba^2+}]^2 &= 4.9 \times 10^{-10} \\
[\ce{Ba^2+}] &= \sqrt{4.9 \times 10^{-10}} \\
\end{align}

My problem solved. Thank You

Comment: There is no _"dissolved first"_. The salts don't have the central command to tell them when to start dissolving, nor the intelligence to find out what other salts are sitting nearby. They all start dissolving at once.

Comment: @IvanNeretin okay, what do you think happened ? What is the $[\ce{Ba^{2+}}]$ ?

Comment: I think that both salts have dissolved a little, and you have all three ions in the solution.

Comment: @IvanNeretin Yes, Both solid will dissolved and make a equilibrium with each other and their concentration will be related with their solubility product. Since the solubility product of \ce{BaS2O3} is bigger, It means the solubility of \ce{Ba^2+} from \ce{BaS2O3} is bigger than the solubility of \ce{Ba^2+} from \ce{BaSO4} and I started from that to count other ion concentration. What do you think I should start to work on first ?

Comment: Salts don't have military insignia either. Any individual $\ce{Ba^2+}$ does not _know_ whether it is from BaSO4 or from BaS2O3. Write down all unknowns, then all equations, then see what you can do.

Comment: Welcome to Chemistry.SE! Take the [tour] to get familiar with this site. Mathematical expressions and equations can be [formatted](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/86/4945) using $\LaTeX$ syntax. I have updated your post with chemistry markup. If you want to know more, please have a look [here](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/86/4945) and [here](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/443/4945). We prefer to not use MathJax in the title field, see [here](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/149/4945) for details.

Comment: $[\ce{SO4^2-}] =3 \times 10^{-5.5} $ is a very odd way to write a concentration. Integer powers of 10 are expected.

Comment: in my opinion, the answer you gave is better than the one I post. You should post it and accept it, and I can remove mine. But I'll let you decide !

Comment: @santimirandarp I got that idea after watching your answer. I think your answer still better. As you say in the first line of answer, Let user have another perspective to approach a problem in many different ways. btw, Thanks

Comment: @valkedin nice! good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just one possible approach:

First of all, the constants doesn't seem different enough to argue that $[\ce{Ba^{2+}}]=[\ce{S_2O_3}^{2-}]$. So for now consider:

$$[\ce{Ba^{2+}}]=[\ce{S_2O_3}^{2-}]+[\ce{SO_4}^{2-}] \hspace{2em} (1)$$

and dividing both $K$s we can find: $$\frac{K_{\ce{BaS2O3}}}{K_{\ce{BaSO4}}}=\frac{[\ce{S_2O_3}^{2-}]}{[\ce{SO_4}^{2-}]}=4.44 \hspace{2em} (2)$$

Now we can solve for sulphate: $$K_\mathrm{sp}(\ce{BaSO4}) = 9 \times 10^{-11}=[\ce{SO_4}^{2-}]^2(1+\frac{[\ce{S_2O_3}^{2-}]}{[\ce{SO_4}^{2-}]}) \hspace{2em} \mathrm{using}\hspace{1em}(1)$$

Using equation $(2)$ we get $[\ce{SO_4}^{2-}]=4.03\times 10^{-6}$

And for thiosulphate: $$K_\mathrm{sp}(\ce{BaS2O3}) = 4 \times 10^{-10}=[\ce{S2O_3}^{2-}]^{2}(1+\frac{[\ce{SO4}^{2-}]}{[\ce{S2O_3}^{2-}]}) \hspace{2em} \mathrm{using}\hspace{1em}(1)$$

Using inverse of equation $(2)$ leads to $[\ce{S_2O_3}^{2-}]=1.8\times 10^{-5}$

The sum yields 
$[\ce{Ba^{2+}}]=[\ce{S_2O_3}^{2-}]+[\ce{SO_4}^{2-}]=0.00002215015=\sqrt(4.906295\times 10^{-10})$